# Image loading function not working

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

Alright, so I've been working on a project, and have come to this problem. I get this message when running my program:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76fa15de in programmingproj.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Here is the code that Visual Studio says is the errors:

```
float **LoadImg(const char *filename)
{
    float **data = { 0 };
    char *buf = new char[32];
    std::string buf2;

    std::ifstream filebuf(filename);

    filebuf.getline(buf, 32);

    // Reiterate over each pixel, very inefficient, needs to be fixed.
    for (int x = 0; x < (IMAGE_SIZE_X - 1); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < (IMAGE_SIZE_Y - 1); y++)
        {
            filebuf.getline(buf, 32);

            // Only copy the values.
            for (int i = 8; i < 32; i++)
            {
                if (buf[i] != '\t' && buf[i] != ' ')
                {
                    buf2 += buf[i];
                }
            }

            // Set the pixel's value.
            data[x][y] = (float)strtodbl(buf2);
        }
    }

    filebuf.close();

    return data;
}
```

Here is a sample of the format I'm trying to read:

```
x   y       Value
1   1           0
1   2           0
1   3           0
1   4           0
1   5      10.159
1   6       5.225
1   7       1.337
1   8           0
1   9           0
1   10          0
```

I only need to load the value field into the proper pixel (x, y).

The strtodbl function is just a quick thing i wrote up to replace atof and/or strtod.

**EDIT:** IMAGE_SIZE_X and IMAGE_SIZE_Y are just constants for the size of the image (97x56).

Comment: `float **data = { 0 };` <-- That's the culprit. Use `new float[y];` then `data[i] = new float[x]` instead.

Comment: While unrelated to your crash, you should remember that images are binary data and so you should open the file in binary mode.

Comment: why don't you just do it like this: `char buf[32];` float data[IMAGE_SIZE_X][IMAGE_SIZE_Y];`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if he were actually reading a binary image then sure, but it appears that he's reading a text file with data he's calling an image -- he has a sample of the data in his question.

Comment: @mah You are correct, this is a text-based image file. It is actually the format produced by MRI machines, which I am writing a tool that allows doctors to view the image and related data points. The value field represents the amount of brain mass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared `data` as a pointer to a pointer, and you're using `data` but you've never allocated space and set `data` to point to it. You must do that before you try to read/write what `data` is supposed to point to.

Comment: This was exactly the problem! Thanks a bunch.